# Find unknow source of JS notification

Tags: javascript, notifications

I have a PWA, that uses firebase for notifications, but when I get the background notifications, I get an extra notification.  It does not have the icon I specify or the "Background" addition in front of the title. I have no idea where it is coming from, except that it has to be in this set of code.  I can comment out everything except the initializing stuff at the top and the `const messaging = firebase.messaging();` and I still get it.

I tried setting my own `messaging.onMessage` to catch that incase there was a default (which there wasn't upon inspection).

Can someone help me track down the source of this annoying notification?

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.2/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.2/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "REDACTED",
    authDomain: "REDACTED",
    projected: "REDACTED",
    storageBucket: "REDACTED",
    messagingSenderId: "REDACTED",
    appId: "REDACTED"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();


/////////////////////////
// The notification comes from the stuff above ^
/////////////////////////

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event){
  const urlToOpen = new URL(REDACTED, self.location.origin).href;
  const promiseChain = clients.matchAll({
    type: 'window',
    includeUncontrolled: true
  })
  .then((windowClients) => {
    let matchingClient = null;

    for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
      const windowClient = windowClients[i];
      if (windowClient.url === urlToOpen) {
        matchingClient = windowClient;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (matchingClient) {
      return matchingClient.focus();
    } else {
      return clients.openWindow(urlToOpen);
    }
  });

  event.waitUntil(promiseChain);

});


messaging.onMessage((e)=> console.log("FBsw:",e))

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
  self.registration.showNotification("Background:"+payload.notification.title,
      {body: payload.notification.body,icon: REDACTED});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a default `onBackgroundMessage` listener that is initialized when you start the messaging function.  I deleted the whole `messaging.onBackgroundMessage()` listener and now I only get 1 notification. There does not appear to be a way to get rid of this default notification.